# How to set TextBox.TextAlign = MiddleLeft?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, textbox

[`Label.TextAlign`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.label.textalign.aspx) is of type [ContentAlignment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.contentalignment.aspx). It allows developer to choose any combination of vertical and horizontal alignments.

[`TextBox.TextAlign`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.textalign.aspx) is of type [HorizontalAlignment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.horizontalalignment.aspx). It only allows *Left*, *Center* and *Right*.

I would like to imitate behavior of `ContentAlignment = MiddleLeft` for a TextBox.

Basically, I am trying to create a custom `MsgBox` dialog (`MessageBox.Show` for non-VB developers). Microsoft's `MsgBox` seems to have its `Label.TextAlign = MiddleLeft` automatically set through windows API. I need it to be a `TextBox` (not a Label), because users should be able to select text and copy to clipboard, partially or in full.

So far I came up with this solution:

1. Have a TableLayoutPanel, one of its cells will contain the above TextBox.
2. Set `Anchor = Left,Right`. This will keep it stretched horizontally.
3. `MeasureText` just before showing (example: Form_Load), and adjust `TextBox.Height`.

   ```
   Dim size As SizeF = TextBox1.CreateGraphics.MeasureString(
                       TextBox1.Text, TextBox1.Font, TextBox1.Width)
   TextBox1.Height = size.Height
   ```

Here is a picture of how it works in action (demo project, not yet a custom MsgBox):

[image]

It seems like a rather dirty approach, not resilient to resizing and text changes. These events can be handled accordingly, of course, but it adds to the overall clutter.

**Question: Is there a cleaner approach?** I am looking for anything that may help implement the above behavior - it does not necessarily have to a be a `TextBox`.

Comment: If you're not averse to mixing Windows Forms and WPF, you might try a WPF Element host and then do your messageBox that way, taking advantage what Xaml formatting provides.

Answer (score 0):

If you add a WPF ElementHost to your form.  Then create a WPF UserControl with a TextBox in it like so:

```
<UserControl x:Class="UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="113" d:DesignWidth="234" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Black">

    <TextBox x:Name="TextBox1" BorderThickness="0" IsReadOnly="True" Background="{x:Null}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center">Hello World</TextBox>
</UserControl>
```

Then in your code you can set the value like this:

```
Me.UserControl11.TextBox1.Text = "Some Text Value Here"
```

Naturally, this assumes that you can use WPF, but on the plus side, you have all the Xaml styling capabilities at your disposal.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I would prefer to avoid WPF.

Comment: @Neolisk - You could try using a RichTextBox, but it doesn't seem to have any alignment properties.  So the Centering would have to be done in the rff code, somehow.